# Проблема с адаптивностью блоков

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер, есть три блока:

1. вертикальный навбар растянутый на всю высоту экрана
2. блок контента
3. такой же блок контента как предыдущий

Проблема возникла во время настройки адаптивности этих блоков,
навбар перестал занимать всю высоту страницы, и поэтому скролл идет по всей странице с обрезанным навбаром, и собственно проблема блоков, на маленьких экранах 3 блок должен вставать под второй, и они должны растягиваться на всю доступную ширину. Перенос блоков вроде решился дивом с display:flex поверх обоих блоков контента, но тогда блоки имеют фикс ширину и не растягиваются на все доступное пространство

вот демо

```css
.nowrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #2a3f54;
  position: relative;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: table;
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nowrap">

 <div class="nav">
  1
 </div>

 <div class="content">
  2
 </div>

 <div class="content">
  3
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) У вас стоит margin сверху у блоков content, а у nav его нет
2) Если flex используете, то нет смысла ставить высоту у каждого элемента, потому что по автомату у флекс-контейнера есть свойство `align-items: stretch`, которое выравнивает по высоте элементы. Поэтому если у content высота 500 px, высота остальных тоже такая будет. Без учета margin.
3) Избыток css у вас, я его сократил, это работает

```css
.nowrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
  background-color: #2a3f54;
  position: relative;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
  margin: 0 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: table;
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nowrap">
  <div class="nav">1</div>
  <div class="content">2</div>
  <div class="content">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант ломает навбар (1 блок) если контент не занимает 100% страницы по высоте, а мне надо чтоб навбар всегда был растянут на всю страницу. И я пытался сделать блоки одной ширины а не высоты, ибо на небольших экранах 3 блок встает под 2, но они почему-то всегда разного размера

Comment: у вас неправильный подход к разработке. Вам нужно тогда делать flex контейнер для двух элементов: вашего nav и content всей области. И именно эта область будет также являться flex контейнером для ваших блоков content. И тогда вы сможете гибко решить свою проблему.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```